# What is Azure SQL Database current version and which SSMS shall I use to backup database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms, database-backups

I have to backup Azure SQL database using Export Data Tier feature. I am getting error - Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server xxx: . (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac). I am using SSMS version 12.0.2000.8 on local. I need to know Azure SQL Database version and which SSMS version shall I use to backup Azure SQL database but before that I need to know SSMS and Azure SQL Database compatibility. I don't find any clear doc about SSMS and Azure SQL Database compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Azure SQL Database is `"V12"`.

And the current General Availability (GA) version of SSMS is: `SSMS 17.9.1`.

I also didn't find any clear doc about SSMS and Azure SQL Database compatibility. But according the link which [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms) provides for us, we can infer that Microsoft recommends  we use the `SSMS 17.9.1` or the latest `SSMS Preview`.

[image]

You can update you SSMS to the latest version and try `Export Data Tier feature` again.

You can download the latest SSMS version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#ssms-1791-is-the-current-general-availability-ga-version-of-ssms).

Here's an another blob maybe is useful for you: [How to upgrade from V11 to V12 SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120685/how-to-upgrade-from-v11-to-v12-sql-azure).

Hope this can helps you.